# R arules - fast way to create transactions

Tags: r, transactions, arules

I have a data set with ~ 1 million transaction rows that I'm trying to convert from a data.frame to a transaction class for use in the `apriori` function from the `arules` package.  I'm using the form discussed in the documentation:

```
a_df3 <- data.frame(
TID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3),
item=c("a","b","a","b","c", "b")
)
a_df3
trans4 <- as(split(a_df3[,"item"], a_df3[,"TID"]), "transactions")
```

However, for large chunks of data this is extremely slow.  Are there any ways to speed this up?

Answer (score 1):

Converting a list (the result of `split`) into a sparse `ngCMatrix` from package `Matrix` is expensive. Mostly this is because we cannot be sure that there are no duplicate items in the supplied transactions and that the items in the transactions are sorted...

Here is some experimental code that directly converts your first data.frame into transactions

```
library("arules")
library("Matrix")

a_df <- data.frame(
  TID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3),
  item=c("a","b","a","b","c", "b")
)

j <- as.integer(a_df$TID)
item <- factor(a_df$item)
i <- as.integer(item)

ngT <- new("ngTMatrix", i = i-1L, j = j-1L, Dim = c(max(i), max(j)), 
  Dimnames = list(levels(item), NULL))
ngC <- as(ngT, "ngCMatrix")
trans <- as(ngC, "transactions")

inspect(trans)

     items   itemsetID
[1] {a,b}   1        
[2] {a,b,c} 2        
[3] {b}     3
```

It takes for a million transactions a few seconds instead of a minute. Use the code with care (it does not check the input data) till it makes its way into the `arules` package.